# PYQt graph plot widget output not plotting as required

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

Can please someone help me with pyqt graph output. The issue is it looks like y axis is floating. There is gap from 0 to 5 on y axis as shown in figure below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71reS.png)

Please assist. Thanks!

This is a simple testing code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
pg.plot(x = [0,1,2,4], y = [5,6,7,8])
status = app.exec_()
sys.exit(status)
```

A possible solution for the problem

Comment: Please assist us by posting some code. We have no idea what your code is doing, all we have is an image of a graph.

Comment: import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
pg.plot(x = [0,1,2,4], y = [5,6,7,8])
status = app.exec_()
sys.exit(status)

Comment: Please add your code in the question and not in the comments.

Comment: It is likely an issue with the resolution if this only happens when the window is rendered on your surface tablet and then dragged over to a monitor.  BTW those are the kinds of details that should be added to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean by the "y axis is floating". There is a strange gap from 5 to 0 where nothing is drawn in.. this code should fix that.

```py
import sys 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication 
import pyqtgraph as pg 

app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
plot_widget = pg.plot(x=[0, 1, 2, 4], y=[5, 6, 7, 8], connect='finite') 
status = app.exec_()
sys.exit(status)
```

Comment: Thanks Caleb, unfortunately it's still the same. It is really wired because it is fine on my surface pro window but as soon as I drag to the extended monitor I see this strange gap. Not sure what's happening.

Comment: Odd. It may have something to do with your machine as on my end the code works. Good luck to you.

Comment: cool, looks like it. Thanks Caleb!